# Displaying generated Id to user using Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a create form with asp.net mvc 3, where a user enters information and submits, to save their typed information to a database.  I would like to display to the user the Id generated with the database row they have just created (via a view for form submitted successfully your id number is...).  Does anyone know of a method to accomplish this?

Comment: What ORM are you using to access your database?

Comment: Sorry Nicholas I am pretty new to the programming world not quite sure what you mean.  I am using Entity Framework with SQL Server, if you can elaborate I can probably answer you better.

Comment: That's ok - EF is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). Do you want to get the primary key id of the new database row? If so, EF sets it for you when you call `SaveChanges` - see the end of @James answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs a bit more detail however there are a few things one should consider when coming up with a data persistence strategy. If you're using the Asp.Net Membership provider, you need to specify that as well. There are methods for returning user info as Bildr pointed out, but I don't recommend using that provider unless you need to as it is being replaced with a 'Simple Membership Provider' in MVC4.

If your using a repository pattern, you could have classes inherit from a common interface. When you add an entity of type T it returns that entity back to the user, when you perform a save it doesn't. This approach comes in handy when you're crossing boundaries, such as with WCF Services and you are passing in a complex object graph with multiple child objects. You can of course, be a little more nimble and have your save method simply return the ID of the created object.

```
 public interface IRepository<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the specified object and returns it back to the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
    /// <returns>The created class</returns>
    T Add(T model);
    /// <summary>
    /// Persist the specified object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
    void Save(T model);
}
```

Of course, if you're building a simpler application, and you are [as over repositories](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/) as Jimmy Bogard is, and using an ORM, such as EntityFramework then you would pass in your object (again, it's by reference) to your context object:

```
  var foo = new Foo{ Name="goo"}
  _modelContext.MyDBSetFoos.Add(foo);
  ((ModelContext)_modelContext).SaveChanges();
  return foo.Id;
```

If you clarify your question, I'd be happy to provide a more specifics. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using forms authentication and you're able to retain the new user's name. Pass the user name along to the success controller, and have it populate a model using the [FindUsersByName method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk59azhc.aspx).